# How to avoid unwanted columns values in Chart in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report where I have to create basic chart for the report.

My data is in the following way

month  sales
jan     100
feb     200
mar     300
Apr     500
May     750

now I want to create a chart in SSRS which has to display in the below figure
[image]

instead of displaying all the columns values(Jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun) I want to show data only for jan and march, how can that be done.

If I take months in Category groups it is showing all the values like (Jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun).

Comment: Can you just not return the unwanted columns in your query?

Answer (score 0):

Right click the month Category Group, select Category Group Properties, then Add a Filter with the following settings:

```
Expression  [month]
Operator    In
Value       jan, mar
```

EDIT: This assumes that your month field is returned as text.  If it is a date field, you will need to modify the comparison value accordingly.